# Regex doesn't capture dynamic groups

Tags: regex

i have following String:

```java
// the length's not fixed. User could append more piped funtions.
{{ some:name | fn:some-function('ay') | fn:default(some:name) | some:other }}
```

The aim is to get an array:

```java
array[0] // some:name
array[1] // fn:some-function('ay')
array[2] // fn:default(some:name)
array[4] // some:other
// and so on
```

This is what i have so far:

```java
^\{{2}(?:([^\|]+)\s\|)*(\s*[^\|^\}]+)\}{2}$

// it spits out:
// full match: {{ thing:name | fn:substring-before(':') | fn:default(thing:name) | some:other }}
// group 1: fn:default(thing:name)
// group 2: some:other
```

Comment: The regex engine does not usually support a capture stack for each capturing group. If you set a `+` or `*` quantifier to a capturing group, only the last capture will be kept in the capture group memory buffer. It is possible in .NET, Python PyPi regex module and Boost, but it seems impossible in your regex engine. Use multiple maching instead or a two-pass approach to extract the full repeated substring and then split with the string split methods that your programming language provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because if you quantify a group with `*` or `+`, only the last repeat will be put into the group. All the others would be discarded.

Instead of finding one whole match, find multiple matches, with each match being an element of your array.

For example, you can use

```
(?:{{|\|)\s*([^|{}]+?)(?=\s*?(?:\||}}))
```

and get group 1 of each match.

Explanation:

- the match will start with a `{{` or `|` (`(?:{{|\|)`)
- match the stuff you want into group 1 (`([^|{}]+?)`)
- Look ahead for a `|` or `}}` (`(?=\s*?(?:\||}}))`)